# Pulling whole transaction details list from solana

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

I am trying to get last 20-50 transactions from solana using node.js via solidity/web3.js .
I can get minimal info using getSignaturesForAddress.
Is there a way to get program log, fee and other information ?

Cheers.

Comment: People would help you if you share your code and they have something to begin. Please read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The problem is, i am unable to find the method to even do this. getSignaturesForAddress is the only thing nearly close to it.

Answer (score 0):

For each signature returned by `getSignaturesForAddress`, you need to call `getTransaction` with the signature to get the full transaction information: https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#gettransaction

Comment: Thank you. I figured this out. The other issue was the rpc endpoint that mainnet as well as serum provides never seem to pull transactions in order. I had to go with QuickNode to actually provide reliable output.